# Encrypt in Java, Decrypt in Data Power

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I am currently working in a solution, where I have encrypt a password in Java (Running in Jboss server), and then send to Data Power and de-crypt in DataPower. I able to encrypt the password in Java. I dont have much knowledge in DataPower. I have got the code to decrypt in datapower, but not sure how to send the key to datapower. Can anyone please help me out. The code is like below,
Encryption Code (Java)
package test;

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.security.Key;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;



public class Test {


  private static final String ALGO = "AES";

  public static String encrypt(String data,String secretKey) throws Exception {
    Key key = generateKey(secretKey);
    byte[] ivAES = {(byte)0x22,(byte)0x22,(byte)0x22,(byte)0x22,(byte)0x22,(byte)0x22,(byte)0x22,(byte)0x22,(byte)0x22,(byte)0x22,(byte)0x22,(byte)0x22,(byte)0x22,(byte)0x22,(byte)0x22,(byte)0x22};
    IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(ivAES);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivspec);
    byte[] encVal = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
    byte[] finalByte=copyBytes(encVal, ivAES);
    String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(finalByte);
    return encryptedValue;
  }

  public static String decrypt(String encryptedData,String secretKey) throws Exception {
    Key key = generateKey(secretKey);
    byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
    ArrayList<byte[]> al = retreiveIv(decordedValue);
    byte[] data = al.get(0);
    byte[] iv = al.get(1);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

    byte[] decValue = cipher.doFinal(data);
    String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
    return decryptedValue;
  }

  private static Key generateKey(String secretKey) throws Exception {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), ALGO);
    return key;
  }
  private static byte[] copyBytes(byte[] encVal, byte[] iv) throws Exception {
       ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       os.write(iv);
       os.write(encVal);
       return os.toByteArray();
    }
  private static ArrayList<byte[]> retreiveIv(byte[] combineByte) {
       ByteArrayOutputStream iv = new ByteArrayOutputStream(16);
       ByteArrayOutputStream data = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

       data.write(combineByte, combineByte.length - 16, 16);
       iv.write(combineByte, 0, combineByte.length - 16);

       ArrayList<byte[]> al = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
       al.add(data.toByteArray());
       al.add(iv.toByteArray());

       return al;
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{


      System.out.println(AESUtil.decrypt(AESUtil.encrypt("Hello", "AVH4TU8AC99dhL2l"), "AVH4TU8AC99dhL2l"));

}


}
```

Decryption (DataPower)

```
<xsl:variable name="algorithm">http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="decryptOut"><xsl:value-of select="dp:decrypt-data($algorithm,'name:danadp',$valueToDecrypt)"/></xsl:variable>     
Decrypted Value: <xsl:copy-of select="$decryptOut"/>
```

But, I am not getting how to share the Key object to DataPower that we generated in Java code for encryption.

It will be great, if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shared secret key object with name 'danadp' and the key copied into a file and imported into the cert:/ folder in the DataPower domain where this code is running.

P.S Remember to prefix the key with "0x" if key is in hex.